# scrollListener in rich datascroller

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

i'm using rich 4.3.1-Final, and i can't set the scrollListener.
On every test i get null pointer exception.

The rich:dataScroller definition

```
<rich:dataScroller id="topScroller" renderIfSinglePage="true" for="table" maxPages="5" page="#{mainSearchBean.currentPage}" fastControls="hide" render="table topScrollerPanel bottomScrollerPanel" scrollListener="#{mainSearchBean.dtListener}"/>
```

The listener method

```
public void dtListener(DataScrollEvent event) {    
 logger.debug("Pageindex: #0 "+ currentPage);}
```

The error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.richfaces.taglib.MethodExpressionScrollListener.processDataScroll(MethodExpressionScrollListener.java:27)
at org.richfaces.event.DataScrollEvent.processListener(DataScrollEvent.java:83)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:778)
at org.richfaces.component.AbstractDataScroller.broadcast(AbstractDataScroller.java:206)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
```

Any idea which is the problem? Any help is appreciated. ;)

Thanks!!

Comment: Check if mainSearchBean exists in moment when you want to call dtListener method (be sure that class is in faces-config or have proper annotation with name mainSearchBean).

Comment: @victor did you find a solution for this? I have the same issue with RF 4.3.3